How to use a Vue component from an npm package in Nuxt.js?
I'm trying to use a component made for Vue (specifically simple code editor) in my Nuxt 3 project.
I followed the nuxt docs on the topic and created a file under the modules directory named register-components.ts and added the following:
import { addComponent
  , defineNuxtModule
   } from '@nuxt/kit'
import hljs from "highlight.js";

export default defineNuxtModule({
  setup() {
    addComponent({
      name: 'CodeEditor',
      export: 'CodeEditor',
      filePath: 'simple-code-editor'
    })
  }
})

But I'm getting an error relating to the highlight.js module (which is a dependency of the simple-code-editor as far as I understand)
One of the errors I'm getting:
The requested module '/_nuxt/node_modules/highlight.js/lib/index.js?v=1c1ab998' does not provide an export named 'default'

Another (On a different laptop, though I'm not sure why I'm getting different errors):
indirect export not found: HighlightJS

Note: both errors show up even if I don't import highlight
How do I set up the module so that I can use it in my project?

"But I'm getting an error" - which error? Why do you import hljs if you don't use it?

It's a different error every time I try something. Even if I don't import it I'm getting an error (and it's also part of the instructions for that specific module). I'll edit my question with the error I'm getting right now

This error is most likely caused by simple-code-editor expecting different version of the highlight.js that is installed in your project. Try npm ls --all to see the version of the installed highlight.js and then check the package.json file inside node_modules/simple-code-editor to see what version it expects.
